# DataBinding: Validate before change

Tags: .net, winforms, validation, data-binding, .net-2.0

[.NET 2]

**Situation:**

```
    class MyObject 
    {
        string Max { get{...}; set{...}; }
        string Min { get{...}; set{...}; }
    }

    MyObject myObj1 = new MyObject();
    // ... code
    txtMin.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObj1, "Min");
    txtMax.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObj1, "Max");
```

**Problem:**

Need verifying `Min < Max` before changing the property in *MyObject*.

If OK, change, if NOK, leave as is(maybe a message to the user).

(sorry if duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do when validation fails (Min >= Max), you can use [BindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.bindingcomplete.aspx) or [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) events from Binding.

Answer (score -2):

In C# 3.5 it can be done with implementing custom [ValidationRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962.aspx).

Comment: ValidationRule is WPF, the original question was about WinForms.